# Native ruby ncurses implementation

Tags: ruby, ncurses

I know that there is ruby ncurses library which accesses the C ncurses library, but is it possible to implement one pure ruby ncruses library? Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

I'm also confused about the motivation for implementing a pure ruby ncurses library. That said, you have a few options:

[curses](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/curses/rdoc/index.html) is in the standard library.  It's not as featureful as ncurses, but would provide a good base to build upon.

FFI would be a good way to get an ncurses wrapper going if compiling C extensions is what prohibits you from using the regular ruby ncurses library (looks like someone [already started one](http://rubygems.org/gems/ffi-ncurses)).

Or, as @mu is too short commented, you could send the terminal control codes directly (I really can't see why this would ever be necessary or advisable though).